# How can I get the size of archive folder without login to Windows?

Tags: vbscript

How can I get the size of archive folder without login to Windows?And I want to just receive the computer's name as variable in to the notepad.
 I'm using `\\kullanici\d$\lotus\notes\data\archive` as path. 
 Here is my VBS code.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Info.txt", 2, True)

TextFile.Writeline "Sonuclar:" & cikti
const dosyaYolu = "\d$\lotus\notes\data\archive\"
const okumaModu = 1
dim fso, dizin, makineAdlari, tekilAdlar, satir, cikti, FarkliMakine
cikti = ""
set fso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.FileExists("adlar.txt") then
 makineAdlari = fso.OpenTextFile("adlar.txt", okumaModu).readAll
 tekilAdlar = split(makineAdlari,vbCrLf)
 for each satir in tekilAdlar
  farkliMakine = "\\" & satir & dosyaYolu
  if fso.FolderExists(farkliMakine) then
   set dizin = fso.GetFolder(farkliMakine)
   cikti = cikti & vbcrlf & satir & " adlı makinede " & dosyaYolu & " dizini ~" & (dizin.Size /1073741824) & " mB"
   set dizin = Nothing
  else
   cikti = cikti & vbCrLf & satir & " kullanıcısı " & dosyaYolu & " dizinine sahip değil!"
  end if
 next
 msgBox cikti,64,"Sonuçlar:"
else
 msgbox "adlar.txt dosyasının vbs dosyası ile aynı klasörde bulunduğundan emin olun.", 16 or 0, "Hata!"
end if

Set TextFile = Nothing
Set WshNetwork = Nothing
set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from exploiting some unpatched security vulnerability, if you're running on a Windows OS and using VBScript, you would need to be able to authenticate to \kullanici with an account that has access to the d$ share. Normally, only administrators would have access to a hidden administrative share like that.

If \kullanici is a Windows 2000 computer though, if you gave Everyone access to the d$ share and to the D:\lotus\notes\data\archive folder, then any anonymous user would have access to it.